# When $N^b (\log N)^c = 2^N$

Tags: logarithms

What b and c should equal to, to say that this equation is correct(the base of log is 2):
$$
    N^b (\log N)^c = 2^N
$$
*I'm a beginner in Math and need this to be done to go further. Would be nice if you gave me some explanation or links to articles to read

Comment: @JimmyR. The base is 2

Comment: $N=4$, $b=1$, $c=2$ is a solution

Comment: I'm not sure this has a solution, if you mean ''for all $N$, ...''

Comment: $N=16, b=2, c=4$ is another solution

Comment: There are infinite possible solutions for many but not all positive real number values of N.

Comment: It's never true for $N=1$.